# Recenter map that crosses international dateline with ggplot and geom_sf

Tags: r, sf, ggplot2, natural-earth, antimeridian

Consider the map of Europe below. Parts of Russia are on the other side of the map. How might I "recenter" the map so that there is less empty space? I guess I need to somehow move the polygons on the left to the right?

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", continent = "europe") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Con you maybe set the xlim of the plot?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work! 
`ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", continent = "europe") %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf()+ 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-60, 200))`
It simply gets rid of the bits on the left. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fic0w.png

Comment: That's a shame. Maybe more luck with [this solution](https://gist.github.com/valentinitnelav/c7598fcfc8e53658f66feea9d3bafb40)? It aims at creating a Pacific-centered map, but I think you can adjust it to your needs.