# New Zealand map that includes Chatham Islands

Tags: r, sf, antimeridian, new-zealand, ggplot

I am trying to create a map of New Zealand in R (sf, ggplot2), that includes Chatham Island. I am accessing the online New Zealand map from Natural Earth. Online I can see the Chatham Islands on the map, but when I run it in R it is not there. I'm not sure what I need to change to be able to visualize Chatham Island as well as the north and south islands.

This is the script I have used:

```
theme_set(theme_bw())

newzealand <- ne_countries(country="new zealand", type="countries", scale = 'small', returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(data = newzealand) +
  geom_sf() +
  xlim(166, 179) +
  ylim(-48, -34)
```

[image: North and South Island of New Zealand]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately data questions are not a good fit for our Focused question/Best answer model.  For open data requests, we recommend the [opendata.se] exchange site.

Comment: The Chatham Islands are at about 176° 30′ 0″ W. Note _west_, not _east_. They're on the other side of the antimeridian to most of NZ, and your `xlim` excludes them out of the gate.

Comment: I have my xlim set as   xlim(166, 179) +
  ylim(-48, -34) is this what I am changing and how should it look? I'm not sure if it is that simple because even if I open the xlim right up e.g. (xlim(166, 250) +
  ylim(-48, -34) the Chatham Islands are still not seen.

Comment: I have added how the (xlim(166, 250) map looks above

Comment: Xlim (166, 194) looks pretty good as far as the position of where Chatham Islands SHOULD be but it is still not visible...any ideas please https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25417/alphabetasoup

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435092/recenter-map-that-crosses-international-dateline-with-ggplot-and-geom-sf but that doesn't have an answer. I knew just changing the xlim wouldn't be enough, but I also don't use R often so don't know the actual solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the detail level of the query is too low to get the islands. Also, WGS 84 lat/long is not the recommended coordinate reference system for this case. Use an appropriate CRS for NZ:

```
newzealand <- ne_countries(country="new zealand", type="countries", scale = "large", returnclass = "SF")


ggplot(data = newzealand) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(crs = 2193)
```

[image]